# How are these numbers stored in memory?

Tags: data-structures

I am reverse-engineering a file format that contains in some places in the binary file what should be a representation of integer numbers. However, I cannot make sense of the relation between the bytes values and the numbers. The sample data I have is the following. Only two bytes seem to be relevant. I have also included the bits representation for convenience.

```
Number  Hex          Bits 
  32   00 42   0000000 01000010
  64   80 42   1000000 01000010
  96   c0 42   1100000 01000010
 128   00 43   0000000 01000011
 160   20 43   0010000 01000011
 192   40 43   0100000 01000011
 224   60 43   0110000 01000011
 256   80 43   1000000 01000011
 288   90 43   1001000 01000011
 320   a0 43   1010000 01000011
 480   f0 43   1111000 01000011
 512   00 44   0000000 01000100
 544   08 44   0000100 01000100
 992   78 44   0111100 01000100
1024   80 44   1000000 01000100
1056   84 44   1000000 01000100
2016   fc 44   1111100 01000100
2048   00 45   0000000 01000101
```

What is the relation between the values in hexadecimal (or bits) and the decimal numbers? Does this correspond to a common data type? For the second question, it might be relevant to know that the two bytes to the left of the bytes above and the two bytes to the right are always set to zero.

Comment: This is not [puzzling.se]...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The idea of posting there crossed my mind... But I expect the formula to be based on computer science concepts since a programmer has decided to store the numbers like that.

Comment: looks like some kind of floating point to me

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, with the two leading zero bytes, these appear to be 32-bit floating point numbers in little endian, as can be seen by inputting the numbers in this converter: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html. If you want to write an answer and get the points, please do so, otherwise I will reply to myself.

Comment: @Tony The problem here is that your question is, basically, "Can you figure out what this person did?" Even though they did it with a computer, this isn't a question about computation, so it's off-topic, here.